# Client Missing Intents when i try to launch it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Writing discord music bot, keep running into this error when i try to launch it

```
TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (/Users/****/Desktop/Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544:13)
    at new Client (/Users/****/Desktop/Dwayne-Discord-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/****/Desktop/Bot/index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
```

I already added the intents as

```
const { Intents, Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
       Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
       Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
       Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const { Intents, Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
       "GUILDS",
       "GUILD_MESSAGES",
       "GUILD_VOICE_STATES",
    ]
});
```

try this
here's a useful [link](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway)