# "CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS" in VSC Terminal - discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot and it keeps saying: [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS`
I'm super confused why it's doing this, I tried researching but nothing has helped.

my code:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
     intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS_MESSAGES 
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready')
})

    if (message.content === 'amber') {
        message.reply({
            content: 'Hello, I see that you have called for me, need anything?',
        })
    }

 client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Comment: is this your entire code or did you leave out the `require` of discord and intents?

Comment: Where is `Intents` and `DiscordJS` coming from?

Comment: I believe `GUILDS_MESSAGES` is an invalid intent. It’s supposed to be `GUILD_MESSAGES` (no 'S')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client Missing Intents when i try to launch it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69323698/client-missing-intents-when-i-try-to-launch-it)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do two things:

1.) Ensure you are including **Intents** from `discord.js`

`const {Intents} = require('discord.js');`

2.) `Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS_MESSAGES` should be `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES`. Just remove the `S` from `GUILDS`

So your code should something like:

```
const DiscordJS = require('discord.js');
const {Intents} = require('discord.js');

import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
     intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES 
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready')
})

    if (message.content === 'amber') {
        message.reply({
            content: 'Hello, I see that you have called for me, need anything?',
        })
    }

 client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Comment: If they're using module only imports it will be `import { Client, Intents } from "discord.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
import DiscordJS, { Intents } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
     intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready')
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'amber') {
        message.reply({
            content: 'Hello, I see that you have called for me, need anything?',
        })
    }
  })
 client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

### Mistakes you had in your code:

### 1:

You forgot to import "DiscordJS" from "discord.js"

### 2:

You used:

**Wrong:** `Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS_MESSAGES`
Which is wrong... the correct one:

**Correct:** `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES`

### 3:

You got:

```
    if (message.content === 'amber') {
        message.reply({
            content: 'Hello, I see that you have called for me, need anything?',
        })
    }
```

In your code, which is wrong, first of all you should create an event that triggers when a new message is sent.

**Example:**

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => { // "message" will be the message that triggered the event
    if (message.content === 'amber') {
        message.reply({
            content: 'Hello, I see that you have called for me, need anything?',
        })
    }
})
```